# Enable "subscription key" for single API of Azure Function in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

I import Azure Function App as backend of Azure API Management.

Azure Functions contains some HTTP Trigger (API), I want to make some of these API become secure by subscription key.

However, it looks like the setting "Subscription required" is attached with whole Azure Function App.

[image]

How can we only set "Subscription required" setting for specific function (Operation)?

Thanks,

Comment: You can only set a `Product` / `Subscription required` on API level. This can not be done on `Operation` level. In your case, deploy a Function App with less operations or delete operations from APIM after deployment

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from MarkusMeyer, I will create another function app for private APIs. The public & private function app will use same App Service Plan to avoid increasing cost.

Answer (score 0):

I found another easy way: Just import function app 2 times.
1st: Import the function that need to authenticate
2nd: Import the public function.